# confusing express mongo behavior. mongo express get method (filter by email) not working

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express

suffering in the "get" method in express and MongoDB!  I wrote express code to get all data and filter data by email. But it couldn't
fetch data by filtering by email.
Finally, I noticed if the email filter method is placed before getting all data, then it works perfectly.
This is very weird for me, Why is this happening? #beginner

```js
1st code(not worked):
        // get / load orders from db to ui
        app.get('/orders', async (req, res) => {
            const data = req.body;
            const orders = orderCollection.find({});
            const result = await orders.toArray();
            res.json(result);
        })


// get order by email filter
          app.get('/orders/:email', async (req, res) => {
            const email = req?.params?.email;
            const cursor = orderCollection.find({});
            const orders = await cursor.toArray();
            const customerOrder = orders.filter(order => order?.email === email);
            res.send(customerOrder);
        })


2nd code (worked):
// get order by email filter
          app.get('/orders/:email', async (req, res) => {
            const email = req?.params?.email;
            const cursor = orderCollection.find({});
            const orders = await cursor.toArray();
            const customerOrder = orders.filter(order => order?.email === email);
            res.send(customerOrder);
        })



  // get / load orders from db to ui
        app.get('/orders', async (req, res) => {
            const data = req.body;
            const orders = orderCollection.find({});
            const result = await orders.toArray();
            res.json(result);
        })
```

Comment: Couple of points to note: (1) `const data = req.body;` is not required. (2) Use `await` on this statement too: `orderCollection.find({})` (3) You can specify the _email filter_ like this (instead of on the returned array): `await orderCollection.find({ email: email })`. Also refer the [MongoDB NodeJS Driver documentation on find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/find-operations/)

Answer (score 0):

Please specify selection filter using query operators. This will return the documents that match the query criteria.

```
app.get('/orders/:email', async (req, res) => {
    const email = req?.params?.email;
    const orders = await orderCollection.find({ email: email });
    res.json(orders);
})
```